Proof of Peirces's Law in The logic book by Bergmann Moor and Nelson

Is this proof correct ? Looks like anything in the world can be proved in the block following ~B. Can we assume A under ~A like is done here in line number 3 ?
If instead of assuming ~B at line 4, some impossibility  was assumed like ~( C V ~C ), that can also be proved in this way. Is this correct ?

You can assume anything you want any time you want.  The limitation is on what you can conclude later. This is similar to how ordinary reasoning works.  I can assume that the moon is made of green cheese, but then the only conclusions I can draw will have the form "If the moon is made of green cheese, then…".  And yes, you're right, anything can be proved in the block following $\sim B$, because lines 2 and 3 are contradictory assumptions.

@MJD, Is it allowed to make those contradictory assumptions ?

@PrithwirajBiswas. Yes, you may raise inconsistent assumptions.

Why is the question closed? I have added more details to the question.

I've voted to reopen. If you assumed $\sim(C\lor\sim C)$ at (4) it would be to prove $(C\lor\sim C)$ at 7.

Correct. And if I had assumed ( C V ~C ) then
~(C V ~C) would have been proved. Is this particular proof above at all legitimate ? What am I missing?

You would have proved $\sim(C\lor\sim C)$ in the context of assumptions on lines 1, 2, and 3, so at the end of the proof you would have concluded $((A\supset B)\supset A)\supset (\sim A \supset ( A \supset \sim (C\lor \sim C)))$. Which is correct. If you live in the upside-down universe in which all the crazy stuff on the left is true, then $\sim(C\lor \sim C)$ is true there too.

Yes.  This is basically the rule of explosion (ex falso quodlibet), in an natural deduction proof system that does not take it as a fundamental rule of inference.
"Anything may be derived from a contradiction."
And you are allowed to raise inconsistent assumptions.  Using this is a fairly standard proof that a false antecedent entails that the conditional is true.$$\neg A\vdash A\supset B$$

If instead of assuming ~B at line 4, some impossibility was assumed like ~( C V ~C ), that can also be proved in this way. Is this correct ?

Indeed.  Anything may be derived from a contradiction; including a contradiction. $$\dfrac{\neg A,A,(C\vee\neg C)\vdash A\wedge\neg A}{\neg A\vdash A\supset\neg(C\vee\neg C)}$$
